# How can eyeglasses improve vision beyond 100%?

Tags: vision

The result of a vision test by my oculist yielded a result of more than 100% while wearing prescription glasses. I wonder, how can a person see better using eyeglasses?

Comment: What do you mean by 100%? Can you give us acuity measures? Like Snellen fractions (20/20 or 6/6 etc)? If you scored above the norm, say 6/20 that means you perform above the normative value. Those normative  values are simply averages and one can surpass that. Also with conventional corrections like glasses.

Comment: @ChrisStronks I wasn't told any measures or units. Just the result that was a percentage. Actualy I was too pleased at the moment to ask the doc this question.

Comment: maybe they meant you were shortsighted and your glasses made you longsighted (rather than "normal" sighted)?